# "TypeError: identStart is undefined" when using Codemirror with XText

Tags: javascript, xtext, codemirror

I'm currently trying to get a CodeMirror editor going with XText 2.25. But since I updated my CodeMirror from 5.51 to 5.59.4 I always get an error that's called when using the autocomplete:

```
TypeError: identStart is undefined
```

I was already able to narrow it down to the function "cursorActivity" in "show-hint.js" where CodeMirror tries to set the variable:

```
var identStart = this.startPos;
if(this.data) {
  identStart = this.data.from;
}
```

This works well when using the editor without XText, but "from" is never set when I'm using XText so it fails. I'm a bit at loss here what I can do. I tried to find out if I can configure XText to set the variable when the validation is called on the XText server but couldn't find anything. I currently create the editor like this:

```
self.editor = xtext.createEditor({
          document: shadowRoot,
          xtextLang: self.xtextLang,
          sendFullText: true,
          syntaxDefinition: mode,
          lineNumbers: self.hasLineNumbers,
          showCursorWhenSelecting: true,
          enableValidationService: true,
          textUpdateDelay: self.textUpdateDelay,
          gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
          extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"},
          hintOptions: { 
            container: widget_container
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem arises because the Xtext-Codemirror bridge misses to set the "from" variable CodeMirror is looking for since version 53. It can be fixed by editing the file xtext-codemirror.js and include the "from" near the "to" variable. But it's more a workaround than a fix.

Comment: feel free to create a bug at github.com/eclipse/xtext-web and provide a patch that updates the code mirror version (also affects WebIntegrationFragment in Xtext-Core)

Comment: newer versions also dont see to be available here https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.webjars/codemirror see also https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-web/issues/125